# Adding new embedded_in documents into a pre-existing document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am attempting to teach myself Rails for my mobile development course. The instructor uses python and Jinja but said we could use anything so I am on my own. For an upcoming project we need to create an app that uses a NoSQL database. I am using MongoDB, specifically mongoid.

I have two Models, verb and tense, where a verb embeds_many tenses. I want to be able to have a link from the verb show page to a new form where you fill out a new tense to embed in the said verb.

I have found many examples using nested forms where you create both at the same time but not where you create a new document to embed in an existing one.

Since I am new to rails I may be getting the verbiage incorrect so I can't find what I am looking for. Any help either an answer or a direction to go look would be much appreciated.

Here are the models I have set up. If I need to provide more please just let me know.

```
class Verb
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :tenses, class_name: "Tense"
  field :first, type: String
  field :second, type: String
  field :third, type: String
  field :fourth, type: String

  index({first: 1})
end

class Tense
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :verb, :inverse_of => :tenses
  field :name, type: String
  field :abbrv, type: String
  field :voice, type: String
  field :mood, type: String
  index({abbrv: 1})
end
```